# Trying to get and display the CGSize of Text() elements in a Foreach()

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I'd like to display Hstacks of a word and its CGSize.width.
But it only works for the first word in the array, the following words are all displayed with that first value...
Could anyone tell me why it doesn't work? Thank you.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
       typealias Value = CGSize
       static var defaultValue: Value = .zero
       static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
           value = nextValue()
       }
   }

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var childSize: CGSize = .zero
    @State var width: CGFloat = 0
    let words = ["this ","is ","just ","an ","example."]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach (0..<words.count) { index in
                HStack{
                    Text("\(self.words[index])")
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.red
                                .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
                          self.childSize = preferences
                            self.width = self.childSize.width
                         }
                    Text("\(self.width)")
                }
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 800)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl9U9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use single state variable for all rows, because its value is overridden during layout and they presented last during rendering.

You have to use same length array to hold width of every word.

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var width: [CGFloat]   // << declare only
    let words = ["this ","is ","just ","an ","example."]

    init() {
        // create state array for width same count as words
        _width = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: CGFloat.zero, count: words.count))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach (0..<words.count) { index in
                HStack{
                    Text("\(self.words[index])")
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Color.red
                                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
                            // store corresponding width for later use
                            self.width[index] = preferences.width
                        }
                    Text("\(self.width[index])")
                }
                .font(.largeTitle)
            }
//          .frame(width: 600, height: 800) // disabled for testing
        }
    }
}
```